# How to convert a file of type <class 'streamlit.uploaded_file_manager.UploadedFile'> to Ptr<cv::UMat>?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, streamlit

What I am trying to do is get a file uploaded via **Streamlit file_uploader** and to pass that png to a function for prediction. This is what my code looks like:

```
if choice == "Upload Image":
    image_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader('Upload an image', type = 'png')
    if image_file and st.sidebar.button('Load'):
        image = get_opened_image(image_file)
        with st.beta_expander('Selected Image', expanded=True):
            st.image(image, use_column_width=True)
            prediction = image_pred(image_file)   # line 52
            st.subheader("Prediction")
            st.markdown(f'The predicted label is: **{prediction}**')
```

This is the called prediction function:

```
def image_pred(filename):
    emo = []
    model = model_from_json(open("fer.json", "r").read())
    model.load_weights('fer.h5')
    emotion_dict = {0: "Not Engaged", 1: "Not Engaged", 2: "Nominally Engaged", 3: "Very Engaged", 4: "Not Engaged",
                    5: "Very Engaged", 6: "Nominally Engaged"}
    facecasc = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(filename, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # line 29 error here
    faces = facecasc.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

line 52, in <module>
    prediction = image_pred(image_file)

line 29, in image_pred
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(filename, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

How can I convert the uploaded file to a suitable format that can be passed to cv2.cvtColor() as src? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.cvtColor()` requires the image data as first parameter, instead of a filename. You can get that like this:

```py
image = cv2.imread(filename)
# now convert the color space
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```